# clang (MS codegen) setup for Qt Creator

Tags: c++, windows, clang, qt-creator

Any idea how to set clang toolchain up in Qt Creator from MSVC2015 distribution?
I mean clang version which is a frontend of microsoft codegen (C2)

project is cmake-based with a generator nmake
but nmake passes some default parameters to the compiler like /nologo and similar and clang reports the error unknown parameters.

do you know how to avoid default CXX parameters from NMake?